# Use string as object name in PHP

Tags: php, string, object

I want to use a string as an object name in PHP.
For example:

```
$name = 'utils';
$obj = new $name();
$utils->test();
```

So I want to be able to call the object by the name of a string (since I don't know the class names beforehand).

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: is there a question there ?

Comment: The above could would do the trick, given that you'd actually call the `test()` method on `$obj`, instead of the undefined `$utils`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$name = 'utils';
$$name = new $name();
```

See [Namespaces and dynamic language features ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php) for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Foo {
 function bar(){
   return 'text';
 }
}

$name = 'Foo';
$obj = new $name();
echo $obj->bar();
```

Comment: Can you please add a quick explanation ?